# Ubuntu 22.04 loading stuck with default updating to 6.x Linux kernel

Tags: boot, kernel

A few days ago after Ubuntu 22.04 updating, the laptop does not want to load. I tried everything recommended for grub repair and other tutorials.

Only one thing helped me: removing the 6.x kernel version and after that Ubuntu reloaded successfully with the 5.19 Linux kernel (previous default version)
[How do I remove newest kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338398/how-do-i-remove-newest-kernel)

p.s This is not a question.

Comment: Perhaps the installation of the latest kernel was corrupted. Can you try updating the computer once again? Does it cause the same issue?