# Ubuntu crashes to blank screen

Tags: crash

After a number of updates on 15/10/23, my system now crashes to a totally blank screen, sometimes immediately I try to login, sometimes later, even if no applications running. I can get a stable system using the Ubuntu Advanced options at startup and choosing "Ubuntu with Linux 5.15.0-84-generic. I have tried the 5.15.0-87 generic recovery mode - enabling Networking and running dpkg -Repair broken packages, but it still crashes to blank screen. How can I proceed to get a working 5.15.0-87 system?

Comment: Uninstall the 5.15.0-87 generic kernel and put the 5.15.0-XX-generic package on hold for a while to prevent it from updating.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how do I uninstall the 5.15.0-87 generic kernel? And what do I do to prevent the -84 kernel updating? I am not sure if the problem is down to the -87 kernel itself, or some error/failure during an update

Comment: If you want to see a list of all kernels currently installed, try `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/q/18654/) and [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/q/82140)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. When I was looking at the installed kernels list I missed seeing the 5.15.0-xx ones cos they'd scrolled out of the window, and I was confused by only finding linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-79-generic at the end, below the Generic kernel. Whats the significance of an unsigned kernel? Also, do I have to purge both the -87 AND -87generic  linux-headers

Comment: [How do I remove newest kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1338398/)

Comment: An unsigned kernel is a kernel that has not been digitally signed by a trusted authority. This means that there is no way to verify the authenticity of the kernel, and it is possible that it has been tampered with or modified by a malicious attacker. Unsigned kernels are more likely to be vulnerable to security attacks, and they may not be compatible with all hardware and software. For these reasons, it is generally recommended to use only signed kernels. If you are not concerned about security risks, you may be able to use an unsigned kernel without any problems.